# My Ubuntu 18.04 Virtualbox machine is suddenly unable to connect to my network

Tags: networking, 18.04, virtualbox

I've been using this machine for a few months now and I've never run into this sort of issue. I am fairly new to both Ubuntu and VM's, so maybe I'm missing something obvious? I've read quite a few articles on clearing cache and cookies, resetting the network connection, and changing the DNS settings but nothing has helped so far. I'll attach some photos of my result of running an apt update and a ping to google.

[google ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of1kP.png)

[apt update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4JKH.png)

Also, my host machine is Windows 10 and is running completely fine. If I try going to any site on Chrome, the result is err_connection_reset, but unfortunately none of the guides I've read on this have helped yet, although I'll keep digging. I'm wondering if I should try using the Bridged Adaptor instead of NAT? Any help will be appreciated as I'm unable to work without a functioning VM.

- I'd also like to mention that I'm running docker in the background

[ip-a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa5TH.png)

[ip route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7LyD.png)

Comment: Your ping test demonstrated that your VM Guest is properly connected to the intenet (5 packets sent, 5 replies received). Your apt test shows that DNS is working (domain names return as IP addresses). So NAT doesn't seem to be the problem. Looks like your http requests (port 80) are getting dropped somewhere. Did you set up any firewalls on the Host, Guest, or Router? Have you tried simply power-cycling your router? (some drop packets when overloaded)

Comment: My firewall is currently off but I haven't tried power cycling the router. I'll try that now and update shortly. So the issue is solely http requests being dropped? Thanks a lot for the informative answer btw

Comment: No luck with resetting the router, not sure what else to do about this? So crazy how this happened out of nowhere yesterday...

Comment: Hmmm. Please edit your question above to include the complete output of the `route` command in the Ubuntu Guest..

Comment: My net tools aren't installed, so I can't even check it. I'm not sure if `ip a` would be helpful? I'll attach the output for that just in case.

Comment: Added output for ip route